# When I rotate device and click tab item the views of the opened page remain in landscape mode

Tags: swift, landscape-portrait

**can someone help please**.I support portrait mode on my device. But only one view controller can use landscape mode. When I open the view controller -which supports landscape mode-and click tabBar item, device returns to portrait mode but view is still on landscape mode.

These are my appDelegate codes :

```
   //Orientation Variables
    var myOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .portrait

   
    var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return self.orientationLock
       
    }

    struct AppUtility {
      static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
        if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
          delegate.orientationLock = orientation
        }
      }

      static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        self.lockOrientation(orientation)
        UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
      }
    }
```

This is my landscape supported ViewController :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        AppDelegate.AppUtility.lockOrientation(.allButUpsideDown)
       
    }
```

Also I have right navigation bar button. When user clicks on the button, screen will turn I have two functions for rotation

```
//MARK: Rotate Device to right
    func rotateToLandsScapeDevice(){
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.orientationLock = .landscapeRight;
        appDelegate.orientationLock = .allButUpsideDown;
        UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
        buttonClicked = false
    }


    //MARK: Rotate Device to portrait
    func rotateToPotraitScapeDevice(){
        
      let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        
        appDelegate.orientationLock = .portrait;
        UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
        
        buttonClicked = true
    }
```

When view is dissapear I turn to portrait mode :

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

       AppDelegate.AppUtility.lockOrientation(.portrait)
        
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
        
    
    }
```

The rotation works fine when I click back it rotates portrait mode. But when I click tabbar item view looks like this :

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my TabBarController class I detect when user clicking items. Then I change device rotation.

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
          
          appDelegate.orientationLock = .portrait;
          UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
          UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
```